# Not getting _id from new record

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, save

I have an api using node, express and mongoose. When I call the api using Postman, the _id value in the model is returned.  When I call the api using the web app build on angularjs and ionic, the _id is null. The record is saved in both cases.

I tried setting headers in the angularjs service. If the fetch all the record, the Ids come back. I have tried setting and removing _id from the mongoose model and angular model

```
// api method 
public save = async (req:Request, res:Response): Promise<any> => {
        let newDfr = new DfrModel(req.body);

        try {
            const insertDFR = await newDfr.save({ validateBeforeSave: false}); 

            if (!insertDFR) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Error Saving DFR',
                    data: null
                  });
            }
            console.log (newDfr);
            res.status(200).send({
                success: true,
                data: insertDFR
              });

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                success: false,
                message: err.toString(),
                data: null
            });
        }
    }


// Service Method on Service Class 
 public saveDFR(dfrModel: DfrModel) {
    return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiURL + '/dfrs', dfrModel);
  }

// Method on component
  async onSaveForm() {
    if (this.form.value.dfrStatus == null) {
      this.form.value.dfrStatus = 'Open';
    }

    const loader = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Saving DFR, one moment please.',
      animated: true
    }).then(loaderElement => {
      loaderElement.present();

      this.dfrService.saveDFR(this.form.value).subscribe( val => {
        loaderElement.remove();
        this.dfrService.showNotification('DFR Template Saved');
      }, error => {
        loaderElement.remove();
        this.showAlert('Error Saving DFR. Please ensure all fields are valid');
      });
    });
  }
```

//client model

```
export class DfrModel {
    constructor (
        public _id: string,
        public projectName: string,
        public projectNumber: string,

    ){}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was sending form.value, an _id key with the value of null was attached. The _id is also attached to my model.   When saving a new document in mongodb, that _id should not appear in the payload. Therefore I just delete the _id key/value pair that is getting submitted.

This seems like an odd way to handle the situation and I think I have something setup incorrectly. If anyone has a better solution for submitting new document, please comment below.  Thanks